# I get a frustrating error with dlmread MATLAB, it cannot read my input file

Tags: matlab, format

I want to read a bunch of files inside a loop function in MATLAB, but when I try the following code:

```
j = (i * 2000000);
A = dlmread('gr_at_0.l_%d', j);
```

I get the following error:

```
Error using sprintf
Invalid format.

Error in dlmread (line 71)
    delimiter = sprintf(delimiter); % Interpret \t (if necessary)

Error in RDF (line 15)
    A = dlmread('gr_at_0.l_%d', j);
```

the following file is one of the many files that I want to read:

'''gr_at_0.1_0'''

I would appreciate any comment.

Answer (score 3):

You are using wrong syntax for `dmlread`. Please read [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html).

The second argument, for which you pass `j`, an integer number, is the delimiter that the function will use to separate numbers in the file.

I think you intend to do:

```
fname = sprintf('gr_at_0.l_%d', j);
A = dlmread(fname);
```

Note that `dmlread` is no longer recommended (i.e. deprecated), you should use [`readmatrix`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readmatrix.html) since MATLAB R2019a.